# Find project by Person Category

Tags: asp.net, linq

I got 4 tables.

**tblProject**

```
ProjID
```

**tblProjectPerson**

```
ProjID 

PersID
```

**tblPerson**

```
PersID

CateogryID
```

**tblCategory**

```
CategoryID

Title
```

I'm trying to find all projects that have a person who is for example a project manager related to it. The problem i'm having is that my repeater returns the same project twice because i have 2 project managers related to it. What i want is that the repeater returns one project even though many project managers are related to it.

Help would be much appreciated

this is my Linq code:

```
string val = dropdown.selectedvalue;
var data = new ModelContext();
var p = from d in data.tblProjects
join pp in data.tblProjectPersons on d.ProjID equals pp.ProjID
where pp.tblPersons.CategoryID.Equals(Val) select d
```

Comment: Are you after [.Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ??

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean ? ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
string val = dropdown.selectedvalue;

var context = new ModelContext();

var projects = (from proj in context.tblProjects
               join projPersons in data.tblProjectPersons 
                  on proj.ProjID equals projPersons.ProjID
               where projPersons.tblPersons.CategoryID.Equals(val) 
               select proj).Distinct();
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Such a simple solution. Had no knowledge of the Distinct()